# How to create two apps which connect to the same database?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Basically what i am trying to do is to create a desktop app and a phone app(for my IT course)  which get and insert data into the same database. 
First i thought i could use normal db with remote access but i found out that it isn't the best practice (also not all hosting company allows you remote access and when they allow it you have to insert the IP of the machines which will make the requests, and i do not want something like that). So what do i have to do ? I've been searching a lot but i couldn't find nothing. What i'm looking for is some sort of guide to do this  because i really have no idea how to do it. Sorry for my bad english and thanks you all.

Comment: Write middleware using PHP, Python, Ruby, C#, or whatever else you want.

Comment: I thank this is off topic !!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need to do is create a web service that both, your mobile and your desktop apps would connect to to save and retrieve data.

Comment: i've searched a lot but i can't really find a good guide ! Can you link me a guide that both show how to create and access webservice in c# ?

Comment: There is no one single way to do it.  You can do SOAP based service, RESTful, you can look at WCF and .ASMX.  It's not something that can be answered with a link.  For most interoperability, I'd look into RESTful as that one can really be technology independent.

Comment: I googled a lor restful web Services, but i could not find something good. Do you Know a really good guide about How to create a restful web service in C# and How to consume it with a desktop app ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943053.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use existing services. I HIGHLY recommend https://parse.com/ . You can accomplish what you need using their service. Their quickstart guides are VERY simple to understand. It supports iOS, Android, .NET(C#) and many more platforms. Also, for what you need, it is free.